# Best strategy for conquering a Bastion Remnant with the items I have?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been looking for Nether wart on my multiplayer server, and just found a Bastion Remnant.  I am on normal mode.  I looked Bastion Remnants up in the Minecraft wiki and they make it sound very very dangerous.  They even say you should have Netherite armor, which I do not.
Here is my inventory:

[image]

As you can see I have access to iron, gold, and wood.  I have plenty of good food, a Sharpness 4 fire aspect 2 Mending diamond sword.  My crossbow is Piercing 4 Unbreaking 3.  I only have 43 arrows but I am right next to a soul sand valley so i can get more if it's necessary.   I also have a Ender chest with these items:

[image]

The Diamond helmet is enchanted with Protection 2.  I have a Looting 3 sword in there.  My main goal is Nether wart, although if it's possible I will also find the other loot.
I am too far away from the main Nether portal to go back, my plan is to get Nether wart, put all my valuable items in the Ender chest, die, and respawn at my base where I can get the stuff back with my Ender chest there.

What strategy should I use to complete my goals with the items I have?  Is it too risky with the loot I have, or do I have a good chance with the right precautions?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think most Bastion remnants are all that dangerous. Main things to note are to take it slow, and avoid opening any chests/angering piglins out in the open. If necessary wall yourself in before opening a chest. That's easier in the bridge and treasure room types than in the hoglin stables, which are very open.

Your main dangers are piglin brutes (keep an ear out/Keep an eye on the subtitles and get your crossbow ready), and being swarmed by angry piglins (don't anger them!).

All that said, I'd be more comfortable with some more Protection enchantments on that armour before going in. Maybe put your valuables in the Ender chest first!

Comment: JSYK, place a hopper beneath the chests to loot peacfully

Comment: Good strategy; worth knowing that breaking gilded blackstone (often generates beneath chests) angers piglins, so care is still needed.

Comment: Died in lava in my first attempt (stupid 1x1 holes in the ground)  and when i was travelling back I actually found another one way closer to home which is great.  I've got more protection armor now, but my sword is now only a sharpness 3 knockback 2.

Comment: Oh, but i have a bow with punch 2 as well.  What is my best bet to kill/avoid the piglin brutes?  I can also craft boats if that is a good method.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't wear the gold helmet, Piglin Brutes will still attack you, disabling shield and making other piglins attack anyway.
2. Enchant your leggings and chestplate.
3. Put Knockback on your Diamond Sword to push the piglins/piglin brutes into the lava.

****Note****

Don't open chests if you decide to wear the gold helmet, as it will make the piglins attack.